# Is there a simple way to simplify the congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a simple way to simplify the congruence? $25^{1203} \equiv 25^3 \pmod{23}$ without subtracting $23$ from $25^3$ a couple of times?

In other words, I would like to rewrite it as:

$25^{1203} \equiv a \pmod{23}$
where $a<23$

NOTE: Someone pointed out that $25^{1203} \not\equiv 25^3 \pmod{23}$, but the question was already answered, so I did not change the question.

Comment: Am I missing something or $25^{1203} \equiv 16 \pmod{23}$ but $25^3 \equiv 8 \pmod{23}$?

Comment: Why am I being downvoted and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but perhaps you could fix the inconsistencies, do you want $25^{1203}$ or $25^{1023}$, edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: I see. I changed it.

Comment: If you're said/discover something's inconsistent in your question **and you already got some answers**, I think the best for all is to ask *a new question* ( and not change the already answered one.

Comment: @Timbuc. That makes sense. Should I change it back to my original question in order for the answers to make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea:

$$25=2\pmod{23}\implies 25^3=2^3=8\pmod{23}$$

Answer (score 1):

$25\equiv 2\pmod{23}$ implies $25^3\equiv 2^3\pmod {23}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify with Little Fermat: as $23$ is prime, any number $a\not\equiv 0\mod 23$ satisfies $a^{22}\equiv 1\mod 23$ hence $a^n\equiv a^{n\bmod22}\mod 23$.

Here, as $25\equiv 2$, we have:
$$25^{1203}\equiv25^{15}\equiv 2^{15}$$
and $$25^{1203}\equiv25^3\iff 2^{15}\equiv 2^3\iff 2^{12}\equiv1\mod 23$$
which would mean the order of $2$ is a divisor of $12$. AsLittle Fermt says it is also a divisor of $22$, this means the order of $2$ is a divisor of $\gcd(12,22)=2$.
Now it is easy to check that modulo $23$, $2$ is neither of order $1$ nor of order $2$. We conclude the congruence is false.